# Algorithms - Picking Numbers. What should be the output for following? 21 or 22?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, max

Problem: Given an array of integers, find and print the maximum number of integers you can select from the array such that the absolute difference between any two of the chosen integers is <=1

Input:

4 2 3 4 4 9 98 98 3 3 3 4 2 98 1 98 98 1 1 4 98 2 98 3 9 9 3 1 4 1 98 9 9 2 9 4 2 2 9 98 4 98 1 3 4 9 1 98 98 4 2 3 98 98 1 99 9 98 98 3 98 98 4 98 2 98 4 2 1 1 9 2 4

Output: 
22

According to my code, the set of numbers for 98 and 99 add upto 21 as there are twenty number of 98 and one 99. However the output desired is 22.

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for(int a_i=0; a_i < n; a_i++){
        a[a_i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(hashMap.containsKey(a[i])){
            hashMap.put(a[i], hashMap.get(a[i]) +1);
        }
        else{
            hashMap.put(a[i],1);
        }
    }

    int max_value = 0;
    int max_key = 0;
    for(Integer i : hashMap.keySet()){
        if(hashMap.get(i)>max_value){
            max_value = hashMap.get(i);
            max_key = i;
        }
    }

    Integer max_key_1 = null;
    Integer max_key__1 = null;
    Integer max_value_1 = null;
    Integer max_value__1 = null;

    if(hashMap.containsKey(max_key+1)){
        max_key_1 = max_key+1;
        max_value_1 = hashMap.get(max_key_1);
    }
    if(hashMap.containsKey(max_key-1)){
        max_key__1 = max_key-1;
        max_value__1 = hashMap.get(max_key__1);
    }

    if(max_key_1 != null && max_key__1 != null){
        System.out.println(max_value+Math.max(max_value_1, max_value__1));
    }
    if(max_key_1 != null && max_key__1 == null){
        System.out.println(max_value+max_value_1);
    }
    if(max_key_1 == null && max_key__1 != null){
        System.out.println(max_value+max_value__1);
    }

    System.out.println(hashMap);
    System.out.println("max_key "+max_key);
    System.out.println("max_key_1 "+max_key_1);
    System.out.println("max_key__1 "+max_key__1);

    System.out.println("max_value "+max_value);
    System.out.println("max_value_1 "+max_value_1);
    System.out.println("max_value__1 "+max_value__1);



}
```

}

Comment: CONSTANTS also go in uppercase letters which is not the case here. Do you have an answer for this problem?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Please read the question and details to understand what is supposed to be the output and what output occurs.

Comment: The point is: you do not use a_b as variable name; thats all. And if I had wanted to give an answer, I wouldn't have commented. I am just giving you a hint how to improve your code in general, make it easier to read for the people you want to spend their time reading your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desired output set consists of `4`s (13) and `3`s (9) - which adds up to 22.

How I would go about solving this problem, is first sorting the whole set. Then loop through the array noting which group has how many members (i.e. there are 10 `1`s, 9 `3`s, etc). And then simply comparing the neighbor groups (if their difference is `<=1`) looking for the highest count. I think this can be done in one pass.

The overall algorithm complexity would be O(n.log n) (due to the sort).

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers

Can you confirm? The problem states that pick the maximum number of integers from the array such that absolute difference between any two of chosen integers is <=1. In above explanation 13-9 = 4, so the difference is greater than 1.

Comment: `13-9 = 4`??? They meant the difference of the integers in the set, i.e. `3` and `4` -> `4-3=1`.

Comment: So you need two numbers whose difference should be <=1 and should maximize the count. Understood.

Comment: @Milin `hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers Can you confirm?` Yes, I've just submitted my solution, it tested correctly against all 10 testcases.

Comment: +1 It took me the link to hackerrank to know what was actually required. Hat of to those who can figure that out from a description, I need examples. OP's comment *'read the question and details to understand'* doesn't help anyone one bit.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, I agree hackerrank explains questions very well, with mathematical precision and with very simple and short examples. The example in this question was apparently one of the test cases, a bit harder to follow...

Answer (score 0):

As input size is small enough, `O(N)` algorithm using counting sort is possible

*(I know it is C++ but the algorithm is as simple as that 3 lines including I/O)*

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int n, a[105] = {0}, ans = 0;
int main() {
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0,x; i<n; i++) cin >> x, a[x]++;
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) ans = max(ans, a[i] + a[i+1]);
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[105];
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i=0, x; i < n; i++){
            x = in.nextInt();
            a[x]++;
        }
        for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) ans = Math.max(ans, a[i] + a[i+1]);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

===>**Javascript **

```js
function pickingNumbers(arr) {
  // Write your code here
  let arr1 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let arr2 = [arr[i]];
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      let breakCall = false;
      for (let k = 0; k < arr2.length; k++) {
        if (!checkDiff(arr[j], arr2[k])) {
          //   console.log(arr[j], arr2[k], j, k, arr2);
          breakCall = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      //   if([55].includes(arr[i]) && [55,56].includes(arr[j])  && i != j){
      //   console.log(arr[i],arr[j],i,j,arr2)
      //   }
      if (!breakCall) {
        if (checkDiff(arr[i], arr[j]) && i != j) {
          arr2.push(arr[j]);
        }
      }
    }
    // arr2.push(arr[i])
    arr1.push(arr2);
    // break;
  }
  //   console.log(arr1);
  //   return;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    let breakCall = false;
    // console.log(arr1[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < arr1[i].length; k++) {
        if (!checkDiff(arr1[i][j], arr1[i][k])) {
          //   console.log(arr1[i][k], j, k);
          breakCall = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (breakCall) {
      arr1[i].push(false);
    } else {
      arr1[i].push(true);
    }
    // break;
  }

  //   console.log(arr1);
  //   return;

  let arr1Temp = [];
  let maxLength = 0;
  arr1.forEach(e => {
    if (e[e.length - 1] == true && maxLength < e.length) {
      maxLength = e.length - 1;
    }
    if (e[e.length - 1] == true) {
      e.splice(e.length - 1, 1);
      arr1Temp.push(e);
    }
  });
  arr1 = arr1Temp;

  arr1Temp = [];
  arr1.forEach(e => {
    if (e.length == maxLength) {
      arr1Temp.push(e);
    }
  });
  arr1 = arr1Temp;

  // console.log(maxLength, arr1);
  console.log(maxLength);
  return maxLength;
}

let checkDiff = (a, b) => {
  return Math.abs(a - b) == 1 || Math.abs(a - b) == 0 ? true : false;
};
```

Comment: An explanation would be really helpful.